# alternar divs por tiempo o con click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
  function next() {
      var nextTo;
      if (to.is(":last-child")) {
          nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
      } else {
          nextTo = to.next();
      }
    to.fadeIn(500, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            transitionBox(to, nextTo);
        }, 5000);
    });
  }

   if (from) {
      from.fadeOut(500, next);
  } else {
      next();
  }
}
```

En el que tengo varios divs que van pasando por tiempo. Pero ahora me gustaría que pasara tambien con el click. Intenté que pasaran con los id en los divs pero no me funcionó. Entiendo que es algo con un evento onclick pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Alguna idea ? Muchas gracias. ([Aquí teneis el jsfiddle por si ayuda](https://jsfiddle.net/shivatazo/v1e1exL8/1/))

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
      transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
  });

  function transitionBox(from, to) {
      function next() {
          var nextTo;
          if (to.is(":last-child")) {
              nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
          } else {
              nextTo = to.next();
          }
          to.fadeIn(500, function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                  transitionBox(to, nextTo);
              }, 5000);
          });
      }
      
      if (from) {
          from.fadeOut(500, next);
      } else {
          next();
      }
  }
```

```css
.boxes div{
  display:none;
}
.sizeR{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1" id="1">
      text1
      <a href="#2" ><img class="sizeR" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/van_los_platanos_pegatina_cuadrada-r144680d35e3e45a0ad2282b310141c3d_v9wf3_8byvr_324.jpg"></a>  
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="2">
      text2
      <a href="#3" ><img class="sizeR" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/pares_de_platanos_del_dibujo_animado_pegatina_cuadrada-r46c488b848514841a3aa27aaec211f22_v9wf3_8byvr_324.jpg"></a>  
    </div>
    <div class="box3" id="3">
      text3
      <a href="#1" ><img class="sizeR" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/deme_los_platanos_pegatina_cuadrada-r25a2e828474b4281b475f1148b382be4_v9wf3_8byvr_324.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puesde pegar el código html? Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías agregar un evento click al contenedor de las cajas y usar el selector [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) para saber cual es el que se está mostrando actualmente.

Tuve que hacer algunas modificaciones a tu código como extraer la función `findNext` para saber cual es el siguiente elemento y no tener que repetir el algoritmo de selección que habías creado. El `timeout` también es necesario limpiarlo en cada transición de lo contrario te cambia la imagen antes de tiempo.

De esta forma solo tienes que usar un evento `click` en lugar de varios eventos individuales lo que te permitirá agregar cualquier cantidad de elementos sin cambiar nada de código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxContainer = $('.boxes');
  var allBoxes = boxContainer.children("div");
  var timeout;
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());

  boxContainer.click(function() {
    var from = boxContainer.children('div:visible');
    var to = findNext(from);
    transitionBox(from, to);
  });

  function findNext(to) {
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      return to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
    } else {
      return to.next();
    }
  }

  function transitionBox(from, to) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    function next() {

      var nextTo = findNext(to);

      to.fadeIn(500, function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          transitionBox(to, nextTo);
        }, 5000);
      });
    }

    if (from) {
      from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.boxes div {
  display: none;
}
.sizeR {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box1" id="1">
    text1
    <a href="#2">
      <img class="sizeR" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/van_los_platanos_pegatina_cuadrada-r144680d35e3e45a0ad2282b310141c3d_v9wf3_8byvr_324.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box2" id="2">
    text2
    <a href="#3">
      <img class="sizeR" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/pares_de_platanos_del_dibujo_animado_pegatina_cuadrada-r46c488b848514841a3aa27aaec211f22_v9wf3_8byvr_324.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box3" id="3">
    text3
    <a href="#1">
      <img class="sizeR" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/deme_los_platanos_pegatina_cuadrada-r25a2e828474b4281b475f1148b382be4_v9wf3_8byvr_324.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

También podrías agregar un [`throttle`](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) a tu función `click` para que se muestre correctamente si te dan muchos clicks seguidos de esta forma.

```
// 500ms es el tiempo que se toma tu imagen en aparecer
boxContainer.click($.throttle(500, function() {
    var from = boxContainer.children('div:visible');
    // .......
    // Codigo del click
}));
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Una pregunta, estoy con lo que me pasaste intentando hacer 2 click diferentes uno para adelante y otro para atras en el 50% por ciento de la pantalla (Derecha-adelante e irzquierda-atras). Igual me estoy complicando mucho la vida no ?

Comment: @David Me parece que si. Creo que deberías dejar el comportamiento actual y poner un par de botones flotantes de dirección como un slider standard para controlar eso que quieres. No olvides hacer `event.stopPropagation()` sino el click atravesará el botón y te disparará el evento de cambiar de slide.

Comment: Vale, es lo que estaba pensando. No sabía lo del event.stopPropagation(), muchas gracias de nuevo